# How will Ubuntu affect the battery life of my Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: application-development, battery, ubuntu-touch

I have a galaxy nexus, I would like to install and try out Ubuntu on it when the os comes out. One of the aspects I have not seen covered in any reviews or demos so far is battery life. How will the UBUNTU OS affect my battery life on the Galaxy Nexus?

Will it improve or become worse...

Comment: Should share this question with Ubuntu phone developers. Does anyone know their twitter ids? They will love these questions.

Comment: lol.elf: E: Funny.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the relative lack of information about this I don't think anyone is really aware about it other than the developers working on Ubuntu for Phones at Canonical.

I'd expect that as with Ubuntu for Android there will be a way to run a terminal window (either by linking up to a PC) or being able to run it straight from the phone, in which case a user could type the command: `upower -d` (*or a similar equivalent for the Phone OS if there is a different one*) into the terminal window to check the power consumption of the device.

Obviously this will vary slightly depending on what you're doing, but you'll probably be able to open relevant apps to "simulate" what you usually use your phone for, before testing and you'll have a relatively good estimate on how it performs.

*Disclaimer: As there is no official documentation on this at the current date, this is just going by the assumption that the Ubuntu for Phones OS behaves very similarly to the Desktop, as such this is but an **educated guess** to attempt to answer your question.*

Answer (score 0):

1. **Officially**, you will not be able
              to install Ubuntu for Android, although it may be hacked
              to existing devices.
2. Also, assuming it is correctly advertised, the dock
             will have a way of charging.
3. With the same battery, it will have a reasonable effect
             so, presumably, longer-life batteries will he used on
             Ubuntu devices

Comment: thanks for the answers. i was pretty sure it was too early to tell still but if ubuntu can keep battery life good on my device it would be awesome. if it is possible to improve upon the battery life that you get with android then that will be even better and a more significant reason for people to choose ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu will only run when docked. Android will stay.

Answer (score 0):

It is far too early in the development process to answer this question.